# HTML Make a three section Content box

Tags: html, css, line, box

I am trying to make a box with a header and two vertical lines in the content section to make box with three sections. I am still a beginner in HTML and have accomplished making the box but cannot figure out how to make the vertical lines. This is what I am trying to make:

[image]

All I need to make the two vertical lines inside the box and fill each of the three sections with content. If anyone could help me out or show the right direction I would appreciate it. Sorry for the horrible photo I had to remove some stuff from the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```css
#container{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
#header{
  width:100%;
  background:grey;
  height:20px;
}
.fourth{
  width:25%;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
}
.half{
  width:50%;
  height:100px;
  border-left:1px solid grey;
  border-right:1px solid grey;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header"><div>
  <div class="fourth"></div>
  <div class="half"></div>
  <div class="fourth"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the following Pen: http://codepen.io/rkieru/pen/JKyYpx

```
.line-navbar li { 
  display: inline-block; 
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.line-navbar li:last-of-type { 
  border-right: none; 
}
```

It is an example of a navigational menu with a similar vertical line treatment, but the CSS should apply easily to your content box design.  The only caveat would be ensuring that they are applied to the box with the greatest height, or otherwise ensuring that the content boxes are all the same height.

Comment: Awesome thank you very much. I think I can figure it out based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't listen to people telling you to use a table. You can do this with `flexbox`. Here's an example:

```css
.header {
  background-color: LightGrey;
}

.column-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  padding: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.column:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  This is header text.
</div>
<div class="column-container">
  <div class="column">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ornare, sem sit amet ornare consequat, nunc turpis accumsan urna, ac hendrerit orci sapien eu purus. Proin blandit finibus eros, ut egestas urna aliquam eget. Integer hendrerit metus sed ligula lobortis, et scelerisque libero congue. Nunc facilisis tincidunt dictum. Nam aliquet ullamcorper nisl, ac congue leo pellentesque eget. Vestibulum dui massa, pretium at ex id, aliquet mattis ligula. Aenean ut porta elit. Donec pulvinar a augue non bibendum. Morbi pellentesque erat ut leo tincidunt condimentum.
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ornare, sem sit amet ornare consequat, nunc turpis accumsan urna, ac hendrerit orci sapien eu purus. Proin blandit finibus eros, ut egestas urna aliquam eget. Integer hendrerit metus sed ligula lobortis, et scelerisque libero congue. Nunc facilisis tincidunt dictum. Nam aliquet ullamcorper nisl, ac congue leo pellentesque eget. Vestibulum dui massa, pretium at ex id, aliquet mattis ligula. Aenean ut porta elit. Donec pulvinar a augue non bibendum. Morbi pellentesque erat ut leo tincidunt condimentum.
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ornare, sem sit amet ornare consequat, nunc turpis accumsan urna, ac hendrerit orci sapien eu purus. Proin blandit finibus eros, ut egestas urna aliquam eget. Integer hendrerit metus sed ligula lobortis, et scelerisque libero congue. Nunc facilisis tincidunt dictum. Nam aliquet ullamcorper nisl, ac congue leo pellentesque eget. Vestibulum dui massa, pretium at ex id, aliquet mattis ligula. Aenean ut porta elit. Donec pulvinar a augue non bibendum. Morbi pellentesque erat ut leo tincidunt condimentum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've recommended the use of HTML tables because the attached image seems to represent some sort of tabular data. I agree you can achieve the same visual result using Flexbox. You could achieve the same in other ways too, for example, using CSS "display:table" to be more specific.

I believe you should not be saying things like "Don't listen to people..." without a valid justification.

Comment: Let me clarify something in case your comment is base on the wrong "tableless design philosophy" that started more than 10 years ago because of something we designers did out of necessity... Tables have a purpose.

As you can read in the W3C spec "The HTML table model allows authors to arrange data -- text, preformatted text, images, links, forms, form fields, other tables, etc. -- into rows and columns of cells."

Comment: Tables are ment to be used for presenting tabular content. According to some sources, tables were part of HTML standard since version 3.2, are valid in HTML5 and they will be valid in HTML5.1. So, if you have some data you want to show, you can use table. You don’t have to reinvent them with bunch of divs and CSS.

P.S.:
Is a good practice to warn about posible issues if we are making recommendations that involve the use of technology that could present undesired behavior on specific browsers/devices that could still be relevant for somebody.

Answer (score -3):

By the picture I think what you are looking for is HTML Table.

Example:

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3">Headline</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Content...</td>
    <td>Content...</td>
    <td>Content...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can use CSS to style the box.

PD: Next time show some code, this way we can have a better understanding of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I can't show the code for security reasons. I deal with sensitive customer information so I can't post any of the code I have. And I did not see the relevance of what I have already done as to what I am doing. I am simply trying to figure out vertical lines. I don't need help with the box so the code for the box is irrelevant. Thank you for your help I had considered a table if I could not figure out this content box.